# Detect synonym word and save them to a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with predefined words/phrases.

Example:
df$term

```
stock
revenue
continuous improvement
```

and another dataframe (df2) which have one column with many rows and in every row there is a text. Example
df2$sentence

```
I used to study at university and in my free time observe the stock prices. Additionally the revenue of every stock
Stock market is my first interest
I always try to continuous improvement
```

using the terms from df I would like to detect for every row the terms and have as output something like this

```
row_number, stock,  continuous improvement, revenue
1,1,0,1
2,1,0,0
3,0,1,0
```

Is there any simple way to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
# Create some fake data
words <- c("stock", "revenue", "continuous improvement")
phrases <- c("blah blah stock and revenue", "yada yada revenue yada", 
             "continuous improvement is an unrealistic goal", 
             "phrase with no match")

# Apply the 'grepl' function along the list of words, and convert the result to numeric
df <- data.frame(lapply(words, function(word) {as.numeric(grepl(word, phrases))}))
# Name the columns the words that were searched
names(df) <- words
df
    stock revenue continuous improvement
1     1       1                      0
2     0       1                      0
3     0       0                      1
4     0       0                      0
```

I have not created a separate variable with the row numbers here, but you could always add that if you needed it with `df$row.number <- 1:nrow(df)`.

Comment: very nice answer. thank you. just a general question for words in your code I have a df (with one column and 61000 rows) and for the phrases I have another df2 again with one column and 2000 rows with total words of all rows around 700000. So I call the command like this `df3 <- data.frame(lapply(df$words, function(word) {as.numeric(grepl(word, df2$phrases))}))` Is it the right way to use the dataframes respectively? I used this command and it run and I wait for result but I am afraid I will not take the result with the volume of text I described. What do you believe for the execution time

Comment: I will need for this? Should I find a more optimus way?

Comment: Hi Keri, yeah syntax looks correct but that might take a while. Also, your resulting data.frame will be 2000 rows by 61000 columns which is pretty big. Are any of the words in your first df duplicates and you can drop them? That would make things faster. Also, since each search is independent you could parallelize the code to make it run faster (check out the package parallel).